# ajax call in a Rails app makes 2 calls to render partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an app which lists upcoming events in a table.  I want it to sort the table ASC/DESC when the appropriate table-header is clicked.  I'm confused about where `link_to's` `remote: true` comes in.

**routes.rb**

```
get '/admin_events', to: "events#admin_index"
```

**events_controller.rb**

```
def admin_index
  date = params[:date]

  @events = Event.order("date ASC, time ASC")

  if date
     @events = Event.order("date DESC, time ASC")
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
    format.html
  end
end
```

**admin_index.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <table id="admin_events_table" class="table-striped" style="width: 100%">
      <thead>
        <th><%= link_to "Date", { remote: true },  id: "date" %></th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Venue</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="admin_events">
       <%= render @events %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_event.html.erb**

```
<tr>
  <td><%= event.date.strftime('%A %B %-d') %></td>
  <td><%= event.time.strftime('%l:%M %P') %></td>
  <td><%= event.title %></td>
  <td><%= Venue.find(event.venue_id).name %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_event_path(event) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "Delete", event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></td>
</tr>
```

**admin_index.html.erb**

```
$('#admin_events').html("<%=j render @events %>");
```

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#admin_events_table #date').on('click', function(){
    $.get(
      '/admin_events',
      { date: "true" });
  });  
});
```

When I click on table-header `#date` then `/admin_events?date=true` is called.  30ms later `/admin_events` is called.  The effect looks like nothing happened.  Inside application.js if I switch the selector to `'body'` and click anywhere on the page my table gets resorted correctly and stays that way.  So I'm guessing this has something to do with my `link_to` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what are you asking for :) If you want prevent `link_to` call, add 'return false' in the end of your callback:

**application.js**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#admin_events_table #date').on('click', function(){
      $.get(
        '/admin_events',
        { date: "true" });

      return false; // <= this one
    });  
  });
```